# SVN commit error says attempt to write a readonly database

Tags: svn, ubuntu

I'm maintaining SVN server on an Ubuntu machine. And currently for some reason it didn't allow to commit. While commit it display following error message.

```
Warning: post-commit FS processing had error 'attempt to write a readonly database'.
```

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This seems to be caused by incorrect permissions on some of the svn files in your repository. A [quick](https://svn.help.collab.net/entries/24663856-svn-commit-fails-with-error-attempt-to-write-a-readonly-database) [search](http://www.gsdesign.ro/blog/error-svn-attempt-to-write-a-readonly-database-commit-failed/) [shows](http://h3x.no/2010/12/04/svn-gives-attempt-to-write-a-readonly-database-error) that it is usually the `<path_to_your_repository>/db/rep-cache.db` file that has incorrect permissions, though there may be others.

You can check the permissions on the files by running the command `ls -lrt`. Make sure that the users/groups writing to the repository have permissions on all the files in the `db` subfolder of your repo.

Comment: Which user should be able to read/write? It looks fine to me, but not working well :(

Comment: It depends on your particular setup, but for me, it was www-data as the user and subversion as the group (the files mentioned in the above answer were owned by root:root).

Comment: I got this error because I checked out the files as root and then tried to commit as a normal user. Fixed the working copy by doing a chown on all the files and then chown again on the .svn dir specifically.

Answer (score -1):

This same issue with me, I also get an error while SVN cleanup. I am using the Ubuntu 16.04. I lots of do google for same issue. But finally I found that I need to **login with root** permission.

Once I do that, I got the solution of this issue.

Comment: Using root is not advisable and does not really solve the problem of incorrect file permissions.